# How to create or update file using Github content api

Tags: api, github

I wanna update or create file (such as ~~.yml, ~~.json) with Github content API.
So I followed directions [written in the github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents), it says to request `PUT` method for update or create. I wrote code like below, but I got 404 error,,

```js
    axios({
      method: 'put',
      url:
        'https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/package.json',
      data: {
        message: 'put method test',
        content: { newData },
        sha: { sha },
      },
    }).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

There is encoded code in the {content} `btoa(content)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 probably means an access right issue: a PUT method needs for you to be properly authenticated in order for GitHub to determine if you have the right to put anything in that repository.
See "[Other authentication methods](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#authenticating-for-saml-sso)", using a [PAT (Personal access token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) and a dedicated "`Authorization: token TOKEN`" header

And you need to replace `{owner}/{repo}` by the actual owner GitHub account name, and GitHub repository name: those are placeholders.